# Python3 error message when running command does not exists

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, python, python3

I had to upgrade mu gnuradio and thus had to build it from source (pybombs didn't work), after the build I get theses error messages whenever I write a command in the terminal that does not exist. Commands that does exists does not give any error messages.

I am also not able to start python3 and get the same error message, though python3 is a command (it shows up when I type python and then press tab in the terminal).

My thought is that the path is somehow wrong but I haven't been able to locate it.

```
:~$ not a command
Error processing line 1 of /home/erik/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/protobuf-3.8.0-py3.5-nspkg.pth:

Failed to import the site module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 173, in addpackage
    exec(line)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/types.py", line 166, in <module>
    import functools as _functools
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/functools.py", line 21, in <module>
    from collections import namedtuple
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/collections/__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    from reprlib import recursive_repr as _recursive_repr
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/reprlib/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    raise ImportError('This package should not be accessible on Python 3. '
ImportError: This package should not be accessible on Python 3. Either you are trying to run from the python-future src folder or your installation of python-future is corrupted.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 580, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 566, in main
    known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 290, in addusersitepackages
    addsitedir(user_site, known_paths)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 212, in addsitedir
    addpackage(sitedir, name, known_paths)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 183, in addpackage
    import traceback
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/traceback.py", line 3, in <module>
    import collections
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/collections/__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    from reprlib import recursive_repr as _recursive_repr
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/reprlib/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    raise ImportError('This package should not be accessible on Python 3. '
ImportError: This package should not be accessible on Python 3. Either you are trying to run from the python-future src folder or your installation of python-future is corrupted.
```